# How to prevent Intellij IDEA from autofocusing on debugger events?

Tags: intellij-idea

Got very annoying thing while hard working - Intellij IDEA thinks that I always should have a look at event which is important as it considers.
No, Skyline, it's not such important as you think =)

For example I run a heavy code and while it's running, I'm looking at something else in browser, or making notes in editor AND BANG!!:
since debug breakpoint was met in my application - IDEA makes its window active and overlaps all others.
There were plenty of situations when I was typing smthg, even login info in input fields and in that moment IDEA came on top of windows so I was interrupted, made mistakes, sent info to wrong resource etc. and get angry.

Is there any chance to tell IDEA to be silent at least on debug events? 
I want IDEA to switch its window to breakpoint place in code BUT I don't want IDEA to make its ON TOP on my screen at that moment.
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to disable Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Focus application on breakpoint: [image]

Comment: found that it's not working properly in IDEA 14  - I've just faced when IDEA made its window on top of others and focused on breakpoint....will investigate of course..

Comment: well, that's indeed doesn't work on my IDEA 14.1.5 (build 14.1.2735)

Comment: accepted since it should work, whatever jetbrains did to their IDE